# Broadcasting between two same-rank tensors in tensorflow

Tags: tensorflow, array-broadcasting, tensorflow-xla

I have two tensors `x` and `s` with shapes:

```
> x.shape
TensorShape([Dimension(None), Dimension(3), Dimension(5), Dimension(5)])
> s.shape
TensorShape([Dimension(None), Dimension(12), Dimension(5), Dimension(5)])
```

I want to broadcast the dot product between `x` and `s` through the dimension `1` as follows:

```
> x_s.shape
TensorShape([Dimension(None), Dimension(4), Dimension(5), Dimension(5)])
```

where

```
x_s[i, 0, k, l] = sum([x[i, j, k, l] * s[i, j, k, l] for j in range (3)])
x_s[i, 1, k, l] = sum([x[i, j-3, k, l] * s[i, j, k, l] for j in range (3, 6)])
x_s[i, 2, k, l] = sum([x[i, j-6, k, l] * s[i, j, k, l] for j in range (6, 9)])
x_s[i, 3, k, l] = sum([x[i, j-9, k, l] * s[i, j, k, l] for j in range (9, 12)])
```

I have this implementation:

```
s_t = tf.transpose(s, [0, 2, 3, 1]) # [None, 5, 5, 12]
x_t = tf.transpose(x, [0, 2, 3, 1]) # [None, 5, 5, 3]
x_t = tf.tile(x_t, [1, 1, 1, 4]) # [None, 5, 5, 12]

x_s = x_t * s_t # [None, 5, 5, 12]
x_s = tf.reshape(x_s, [tf.shape(x_s)[0], 5, 5, 4, 3]) # [None, 5, 5, 4, 3]
x_s = tf.reduce_sum(x_s, axis=-1) # [None, 5, 5, 4]
x_s = tf.transpose(x_s, [0, 3, 1, 2]) # [None, 4, 5, 5]
```

I understand this is not efficient in memory because of the `tile`. Also, `reshape`'s, `transpose`'s `element-wise` and `reduce_sum`s operations can hurt the performance for larger tensors. Is there any alternative to make it cleaner?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do you have any evidence that `reshape`s are expensive? The following uses a reshape and dimension broadcasting:

```
x_s = tf.reduce_sum(tf.reshape(s, (-1, 4, 3, 5, 5)) *
                    tf.expand_dims(x, axis=1), axis=2)
```

Comment: Thanks for your help. Indeed your impl (`x_s2`) is faster than the OP (`x_s`)
    > %timeit sess.run(x_s)
    1000 loops, best of 3: 365 µs per loop

    > %timeit sess.run(x_s2)
    1000 loops, best of 3: 243 µs per loop

Answer (score 0):

Just some advice and maybe not faster than yours. First split `s` with `tf.split` into four tensors, then use `tf.tensordot` to get final result, like this

```
splits = tf.split(s, [3] * 4, axis=1)
splits = map(lambda split: tf.tensordot(split, x, axes=[[1], [1]]), splits)
x_s = tf.stack(splits, axis=1)
```